# How do I change the default resolution of the android camera API?

Tags: android, camera, resolution

I can get the android camera resolutions available with

```
Camera.Parameters cp = mCamera.getParameters();
List<Camera.Size> sl = cp.getSupportedPictureSizes();
Log.d("Cam Size", "width = " + sz.width + " height = " + sz.height);
for(Camera.Size s : sl){
    Log.d("Res", "width = " + s.width + " height = " + s.height);
    cp.setPictureSize(s.width, s.height);
}
```

it shows from 5312 X 2988 to 640 X 480.
When I get the current res using

```
cp.getPictureSize()
```

it gives 1920 X 1080.
The stock Android camera setting is 5312 X 2988 and I can change the res with

```
mCamera.setParameters(cp);
```

The Camera keeps resetting back to 1920 X 1080 which must be the default for the API. Can I change this default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I change this default?

Not from an app. That will be whatever the device manufacturer and/or Google chooses.

Comment: I see, so the stock camera simply keeps the setting entered.  Do you know if most Android cameras have default at 1920 X 1080?  Is the res picked the most stable for the device?

Comment: @Azkik: "Do you know if most Android cameras have default at 1920 X 1080?" -- I have never examined the default. Pick what the *user* wants, not some arbitrary value. "Is the res picked the most stable for the device?" -- I doubt that is a criterion, and developers should not be assuming that the default is any more or less "stable" and is any other resolution.

Comment: _if most Android cameras have default at 1920 X 1080?_ The answer is **no**. Most of manufactured Android devices don't even support full HD _playback_! But for most of new high-end devices (the best-selling models of summer 2014), video capture at 1080p is default.